# Cancan allow updating specific attribute of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I want to use cancan to allow updating a certain attribute of a model but not others. Here is what my update action looks like.

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   load_and_authorize_resource

   def update
   respond_with User.update(params[:id], params[:user])
   end
 end
```

if resource.instance_of? Teacher

```
 can [:read, :update], User do |user|
   resource.users.include? user
 end
```

I want Teacher to be able to modify user.course_id but nothing else. How should I change

```
 can :update, User
```

to do what I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm.. I"m not sure if the 'action' in a cancan ability has to explicitly be an action in the controller. If it doesn't, you could do...

```
# ability.rb
if resource.instance_of? Teacher 
  can :update_course, User
end


# Controller
def update
  params[:user].delete(:course_id) if cannot? :update_course, User
  respond_with User.update(params[:id], params[:user])
end
```